# Could not load type 'FUP.ER.XMLGeneratorER from assembly FUP.ER

Tags: event-receivers

I have created a SharePoint 2007 feature with a List Item event receiver.
However, I am getting the following error:

**Could not load type 'FUP.ER.XMLGeneratorER from assembly FUP.ER**

```
- I have added the assembly in the web config as safe.
- dll is deployed in GAC
- I copied the dll in inetpub\...\site\bin
```

What else should I do?

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
  Id="07D685A1-48CF-467E-9AE9-336F3D077107"
  Title="FUP.ER.GnerateXml"
  Description="" 
  Scope="Web"
  Hidden="FALSE"
  ImageUrl="">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="Elements.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="100">      
    <Receiver>
      <Name>XMLGeneratorERItemAdded</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
      <Assembly>FUP.ER, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ad5d71e9ee476a7e</Assembly>
      <Class>FUP.ER.XMLGeneratorER</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>     
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

---

Event receiver:

```
namespace FUP.ER
{

    public class XMLGeneratorER: SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An item was added.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {

                base.ItemAdded(properties);
        }
     }
}
```